# Musicbrainz GET artists name in Angular with ng-repeat | JSON

Tags: angularjs, json

I'm a bit new here and I have to go back on Angular for a small project of application.

I have to get a list of artist, written in a JSON object provided by MusicBrainz (metadata for music artists).

I've made a request for example with the link below

```
http://search.musicbrainz.org/ws/2/artist/?query=muse%20e*&fmt=json
```

Which return a JSON object with the result of a research with "muse" tag. But i would like to print those "artists" names in my html.

I'm using AngularJS.

I've made this little block of code in my app.js :

```
.controller('artisteCtrl', function($http, $scope){
    $scope.listenoms = [];

    $http.get('http://search.musicbrainz.org/ws/2/artist/?query=muse%20e*&fmt=json')
        .success(function(data){
            $scope.listenoms = data;
            console.log($scope.listenoms);
    })
})
```

Then my HTML ng-repeat looks like :

```
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="name in listenoms">
        {{data['artist-list'].artist[0].area}}
    </li>
</ul>
```

Nothing is working. It gets the object and show it in the console, but i can't have access to the children...

Thanks for your help guys !

Comment: you're not using the `name` variable that's listed in your `ng-repeat` block

Comment: I answered your question and you should keep my answer marked as the answer and create a new question instead, otherwise it becomes too broad and isn't useful for future use for others.

Comment: @DavidL Oh okay nice ! Thanks for your advice, I'm totally new here, fine !

Comment: No problem at all :). Just trying to point you in the right direction!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The $http response is not a data object, but rather a response object (see [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http)), composed of the following properties:

```
data – {string|Object} – The response body transformed with the transform functions.
status – {number} – HTTP status code of the response.
headers – {function([headerName])} – Header getter function.
config – {Object} – The configuration object that was used to generate the request.
statusText – {string} – HTTP status text of the response.
```

Simply assign the response.data object to your scope property:

```
$scope.listenoms = data.data;
```

or, to follow a better convention, rename data to "response" and use `.then()` instead of `.success()` since `.success()` is now considered deprecated:

```
$http.get('http://search.musicbrainz.org/ws/2/artist/?query=muse%20e*&fmt=json')
    .then(function(response){
        $scope.listenoms = response.data;
        console.log($scope.listenoms);
    }
)
```

Finally, you are using the incorrect object structure from the payload in your template.  It should look like the following:

```
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="artist in listenoms['artist-list'].artist">
        {{artist.area}}
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: also, he should use `.then()` rather than `.success()`

Comment: Okay fine, thanks for your answers guys, it's more clean on app.js side, but for the displaying part, how can I deal with a children who has a dash in the name ? 

Like : "artist-list"

Comment: @MaximeBissonnier I've updated my answer to handle the data structure that is returned from that endpoint.

Comment: Thank you so much @DavidL ! You helped me a lot, I hope I won't be stuck in some others problems... I have to deal with this app tonight and finish it..

Comment: @MaximeBissonnier happy to help!